# remote rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) while pushing to heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

i want push my django API to heroku to host using git but i am getting error while pushing "git push heroku master".
i tried buildpacks but still getting this error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok i got the solution my requirements file extension text instead of txt.now working fine.